# opencart category api return {"category":null} error

Tags: php, opencart, php-curl, opencart-module

I created api to fetch category list from opencart to use for android application. There are many category list already available but when I tried to hit api getting error message "{"category":null}"

catalog->controller->api

Following are the code:

```
<?php

class ControllerApicategory extends Controller
{
public function index() 
{
        
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $json = array();
        $json['category'] = array();
        $filter_data = array();
         
         $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($filter_data);
        # -- $_GET params ------------------------------
        
        if (isset($this->request->get['id'])) {
            $category_id = $this->request->get['id'];
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        # -- End $_GET params --------------------------

        
        
        $json['category'] = array(
            'id'                    => $category['category_id'],
            'name'                  => $category['name'],
            'description'           => $category['description'],
            'href'                  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'category_id=' . $result['category_id'])
        );

        $json['category'] = $data['category'];
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }
    }
```

Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Mistakes

1. getCategory function accept integer parameter
2. 

> $json[‘category’]= $data[‘category’];

public function index()
{

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');
    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    $json = array();
    $json['category'] = array();
 
    
    if (isset($this->request->get['id'])) {
        $category_id = $this->request->get['id'];
    } else {
        $category_id = 0;
    }

     $category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
    
    $json['category'] = array(
        'id'                    => $category['category_id'],
        'name'                  => $category['name'],
        'description'           => $category['description'],
        'href'                  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'category_id=' . $category['category_id'])
   );
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```